# Dropping the first Decimal place in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, date, decimal

I have a data frame that looks close to this

| Country | Year | Production |
| --- | --- | --- |
| United states | 2000.0 | 4135059.0 |
| United states | 2001.0 | 3759340.0 |
| United States | 2002.0 | 4516827.0 |

I am trying to drop the decimal place in each column.

```
df.style.set_precision(0)
```

Did not change anything

And

```
df.astype(int)
df.round()
```

Did not fix it either.

Is there another option I am missing?

Comment: As long as the column is float, it will be displayed with a decimal.  If you want them to be integers, then convert them to integers.  Note that `df.astype(int)` does not change anything in place.  You need `df = df.astype(int)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `format` to set `precision` to `0`:

```
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO

data = StringIO("""Country;Year;Production
United states;2000.0;4135059.0
United states;2001.0;3759340.0
United States;2002.0;4516827.0
""")

df = pd.read_csv(data, sep=';')

df.style.format(precision=0)
```

Alternative (change dtype to `int`):

```
df.set_index('Country').astype(int).reset_index()
```

Output:

```
         Country  Year  Production
0  United states  2000     4135059
1  United states  2001     3759340
2  United States  2002     4516827
```

Hope this answers you question.

Comment: Another option: `df = df.astype({'Country': str, 'Year': int, 'Production': int})`

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is the most efficient way, but you can loop through the values in the data frame and round the year. Using the parameters passed, for example `round(1.1234, 2)` will return the number rounded 2 to the second decimal place, and so on.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).